# SKPhysicBody In the Wrong position

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am creating a simple Sprite Kit game however when i am adding the PhysicsBody to one of my sprites it seems to be going in the wrong position. i know that it is in the wrong position as i have have set 
`skView.showsPhysics = YES;`
and it is showing up in the wrong position.

[image]

The Square in the bottom corner is the physics body for the first semicircle. I am using a square at the moment just for testing purposes.

My app includes view following and follows my main sprite when it moves. I implemented this by following apples documentation and creating a 'myworld' node and creating all other nodes from that node.

```
 myWorld = [SKNode node];

    [self addChild:myWorld];

 semicircle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"SEMICRICLE.png"];
    semicircle.size = CGSizeMake(semicircle.frame.size.width/10, semicircle.frame.size.height/10);
    semicircle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:semicircle.frame.size];
    semicircle.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    semicircle.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    semicircle.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    semicircle.name = @"semicircle";
    [myWorld addChild:semicircle];
```

To centre on the node I call these methods

```
- (void)didSimulatePhysics
 {
[self centerOnNode: [self childNodeWithName: @"//mainball"]];
  }

  - (void) centerOnNode: (SKNode *) node
  {
CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
node.parent.position = CGPointMake(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x,                                                   node.parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y);
   }
```

I don't know if the my world thing makes any difference to the SkPhysics body...

Answer (score 2):

SKPhysicsBody starts at coordinates 0,0 which is at the bottom left hand corner. If you make the area smaller, as you did by width/10 and height/10, you decrease the size but from the bottom left.

I think what you are looking for is [bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:) which allows you to manually set the center from which you base your physics body area on.

**Update:**

Based on what I understand, your smallest semi circle pic size is the same as the screen size. I would suggest you modify the image size to something like the example I have. You can then set the sprite's position as required and set the physics body to the half of the image containing your semi circle.
[image]

Comment: so i did what you said and it did move the physics body to the right position...however in this game what happens is all of the semicircles spin when you hold the buttons down the bottom. When you spin the semicircle the physics body seems to do orbit the old area in the corner instead of spinning on the spot.I think that the problem has something to do with the view following as i did a test project exactly the same that doesn't use the my world view following thing thing and it worked completely fine.

Comment: Not sure what to make of that. Your physics body is part of the object so it should only move the way the object does... Is the center semi circle an independent object or is is part of a background pic which rotates?

Comment: Yeah it's quite difficult to explain...yes the semicircle is an independent object as are all of the semicircles in the picture...I'm think of just restarting this project and trying to code it differently

Comment: Don't give up yet. Try out everything you can think of. Make sure your physics body defined center point is actually at the center of the sprite or it will orbit the center. Also, if the semi circle is independent, I have to wonder why your rect physics body was at the lower left. Is your semi circle sprite the size of your screen?

Comment: Yes i was using quite a large image of a semicircle and scaling it down quite a lot to fit on the screen.  I have now down sized the image in another program and it is now already the right size for the screen. There is no down scaling in Xcode yet i am still getting the same problem. You said to make sure that the that the centre point is the centre of the sprite. i have used the method `bodywithrectangleofsize: centre` and have set the centre to `semicircle.position`...Is this correct

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html     This is the documentation i used to implement the view following

Comment: Try using something like this self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height) center:CGPointMake(0,0)];  You might need to change self to your object name, depending on your code. The center will automatically be the center of your rect. If you need to change the center coordinates, feel free to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your centerOnNode call should be put in the didEvaluateActions function instead of the didSimulatePhysics function. This is because you need to move the world before the physics are drawn so that they stay in sync. Similar question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24804793/5062806