# Sprite kit skview.showPhysics bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

[image]

Here is the code for setting the characters physics body.

```
character.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:character.size];
```

It works fine, I mean it stays where I want it to but as you can see it displays the `character`'s physics body in the bottom left of the screenshot (which is the grey box).

Is this a bug or can this be fixed?

Comment: It appears to be when I set the ancho point to (0.5,0.5) for the `SKScene` the physics outline do not change there anchor point with it, how would this be fixed without removing the custom anchor point

Comment: remove the custom anchorpoint, it only slides the texture around the node position. If you need a different anchor for rotation, add an additional node as parent that acts as an anchorpoint

Comment: is there no other way of actually editing the `showPhysics` attribute so it fits with my anchor point? @LearnCocos2D

Comment: No, because anchorpoint just shifts around the texture position, it does not affect physics in any way. You can do everything you can do with anchorPoint by either changing the position or by introducing another parent node (for rotating/scaling offset from center).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which may or may not solve yours.

It looks like you are using some sort of viewport system. Perhaps with a node called `world` and one called `camera`? If this is the case then you must be moving your `world` node every frame in order to center the content correctly? When drawing physics, you need to move the `world` node at `-didEvaluateActions` instead of `-didSimulatePhysics`